# How we can read zip file and get information of files or folders contains without unzipping in PHP?

Tags: php, zip

What I actually wanted to do is read zip file and then if it does contain folder then refuse it with some message.

I want user should upload zip file with files only without any directory structure. 
So I want to read zip file contains and check file structure.
I am trying with following code snippet.

```
$zip = zip_open('/path/to/zipfile'); 
while($zip_entry = zip_read($zip)){
       $filename = zip_entry_name($zip_entry);
       //@todo check whether file or folder.  
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have sorted out.
I am now checking filename as strings wherever I am getting string ending with "/" that am treating as directory else as file.

Answer (score 1):

can't you parse path of $filename? something like `$dirName = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_DIRNAME)`

Comment: No you can't. You an do that if you extract the file(s). pathinfo expects the $filename to be a file physically present on the disk.

Comment: yes we cannot check whether those are files or folders using php functions like is_dir or is_file or pathinfo. As these file does not have physical path.